# Trouble setting up wvdial

Tags: wireless, networking, wvdial

I'm using nokia x2-00 as modem and idea as service provider.my wvdial settings are as follows:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet",,0,0
; Phone = *99#
ISDN = 0
Modem Type = USB Modem
; Password = 
New PPPD = yes
StupidMode = 1
; Username = 
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0
Baud = 460800
```

While connecting I get message as follows:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet",,0,0
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet",,0,0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Configuration does not specify a valid phone number.
--> Configuration does not specify a valid login name.
--> Configuration does not specify a valid password.
```

I tried changing the phone number to `*99***1#` and username and password as my phone number, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors i believe, shouldn't it be:

> [Dialer Defaults]
>
> Init1 = ATZ
>
> Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
>
> Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet",,0,0
>
> **Phone = *99#**
>
> ISDN = 0
>
> Modem Type = USB Modem
>
> **Password =**
>
> New PPPD = yes
>
> StupidMode = 1
>
> **Username =**
>
> Modem = /dev/ttyACM0
>
> Baud = 460800

Also you should check if your provider doesn't really use a username and password.